# siunitx : forced parenthesis

Tags: siunitx, parenthesis

Is there a way to force `siunitx` use parenthesis systematically ?

I tried `bracket-numbers` but it's only if :

> There are certain combinations of numerical input which can be ambiguous.

I'd like to avoid a new macro even with optional parameter.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\newcommand{\Num}[2][]{$(\num[#1]{#2})$}

\RequirePackage[%
    locale=FR,%
    detect-all,%
    table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    explicit-sign = +,
    bracket-numbers = false
    ]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\num{5,3} % -> (+5,3)

\num{-5,3} % -> (-5,3)

\Num{5,3} % -> (+5,3) ok

\Num{-5,3} % -> (-5,3) ok

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps `\newcommand{\pair}[2]{(\num{#1},\num{#2})}`?

Comment: What are the parentheses here for? There's no ambiguity so they are not needed.

Comment: @JosephWright In french schools one presents relative numbers as this during a first learning period : 1 is (+1) explicitelly to have a symetric notation to (-3). Then one writes (+1)+(-3)=(-2), after some times it becomes more or less naturally : 1-3=-2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

A slight modification on egreg's idea:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\RequirePackage[%
    locale=FR,%
    detect-all,%
    table-number-alignment = center-decimal-marker,
    inter-unit-product = \ensuremath{{}\cdot{}},
    group-minimum-digits=4,
    explicit-sign = +,
    bracket-numbers = false
    ]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\pair}[1]{(\num{#1})}

\num{5,3} % -> (+5,3)

\num{-5,3} % -> (-5,3)

\pair{5,3}

\pair{-5,3} + \pair{-5,2}

\pair{1} + \pair{-3} = \pair{-2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ok the new macro solution is the easy one ;-) thank you, but I'd expected a pure siunitx solution. In fact I use this to typeset numbers with lua code, and it's easer to have just one option to adjust instead of choosing witch macro to use. And above all, if a siunitx solution is not possible, I prefer use lua to put the () directly instread of switching of macro.

Comment: Perhaps this will require digging into `siunitx` a bit and may end in patching!

Answer (score 1):

You can redefine the `\num`-command to include brackets:

```
\let\oldnum\num
\renewcommand{\num}[1]{(\oldnum{#1})}
```

This will only affect the way `\num` is displayed, `\numrange` etc. are not affected by this change.

Comment: I need both possibilities at the same time in the same document, `num` globally will block the normal behavior